# How to print login form on page

Tags: forms, users

How to print login form with destination url on a page using code in drupal 7  ?

Comment: have you searched the web? what did you try? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995551/drupal-render-login-form-programatically

Comment: right now i am using it, but i cant change destination url with it

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to print login form block

```
<?php
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
?>
```

For login redirect to destination you can use [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module

Project page says

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Comment: with `print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));` i can't change destination url

Comment: You can use rules module to redirect user to custom url on login...

Comment: by using rules all users will be redirected to a page after login, but i want them to redirect only if they are logged in with form on a specific page and the page is not static page as well , it will be a referenced node.

Comment: To avoid PHP Strict errors, use $form = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
                                print(drupal_render($form));

Answer (score 1):

Outputting the form:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995551/drupal-render-login-form-programatically

Redirecting after submit:

https://drupal.org/node/290462

Comment: by using above all users will be redirected, i want them redirected if they login from a specific page with login form.

Comment: I am sure you can set a session variable when your particular page has been hit and then check it in your hook.